# ArrayAdapter Not showing anything for the listview

Tags: android

I have a simple list view I want to populate using an array adapter.  I just want to put a string in it.  What I have makes sense to me but clearly isn't working as there is nothing being displayed!  I'm fairly sure my error lies in here:

```
public class PartiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private List<String> parties;

public PartiesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> list) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.parties = list;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater viewInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.parties_item, null);
    }
    String party = parties.get(position);

    TextView party_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.party_item);
    party_name.setText(party);

    return view;
}
}
```

Am I populating each row correctly?

Comment: Please post the all the code for the Adapter.

Comment: just posted the rest of the adapter although there isn't much more to it

Comment: party is never null.. lol.. Sir?

Comment: turns out the issue was that I didn't implement a getCount() method.  It must default to 0.  Thank you though.  I'll post this as an answer for others.

Comment: You do not need to implement `getCount()` on `ArrayAdapter`. I bet you if you call `super.getCount()` it will work the same. It is already done for you. If you look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) you can see this.

Comment: The fact is you don't need to override `getCount` if you call `super(context, resource,list);` in your constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your own list variable in the Adapter, you should use the inbuilt list like this

```
public class PartiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public PartiesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> list) {
        super(context, resource,list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater viewInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.parties_item, parent,false);
        }
        String party = getItem(position);

        TextView party_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.party_item);
        party_name.setText(party);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also while inflating you should try to avoid passing null and use something like this `view = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.parties_item, parent,false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because of the way you are extending `ArrayAdapter`. `ArrayAdapter` has this constructor that does what you want:

`ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, java.util.List<T>)`

Just remember that `ArrayAdapter` requires you to have a `TextView` on the layout you provide or use the other version of this constructor that lets you specify and id of a `TextView` within the layout.

There is no need for you to extends `ArrayAdapter` for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to implement a `getCount()` method in the `ArrayAdapter`

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
    return parties.size();
}
```

Comment: This is true if implementing `BaseAdapter` not when extending `ArrayAdapter` because it already knows the size of the `List`; it is being passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
new PartiesAdapter(...)
```

call

```
new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.parties_item, R.id.party_item, parties)
```

Also delete `PartiesAdapter` as it is trying to do something the `ArrayAdapter` can do out of the box.